# How can I control headers uploaded through a FileReference object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently started using Flash Builder for the first time after developing C++ and C# for a long time.

I am using a `FileReference` object to upload a file to a server using its `upload` method. However, on the server-side, I need to receive a `X-File-Name` header. How can I control which headers are sent through the Flash object in Flex/ActionScript?

I couldn't find any resources about this anywhere. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot. The FileReference object is provided out—of—the—box and is not that much configurable.

But you can load the file, create your own sockets and reimplement the protocol with your needs (this is feasable if you don't need a lot of features).

Here is an example of how it works : http://googolflex.com/?p=367

Comment: Are there different ways of determining the filename from the server then using FileReference?

Comment: Yes. It sends a multipart message. One of the part holds the filename. See the HTTP Request example here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html You can easily extract this information from the httprequest